# Draw on a custom ImageView using a Canvas on top of bitmap

Tags: android, canvas, imageview

I have an Android app where i need to take a photo, display it and then be able to put a mark icon it.
I succeeded in taking the picture and displaying it on an ImageView, but now i try to put the mark on it, so i searched and found that a good solution was to subclass ImageView, so that's what i did, but when i draw the canvas on my custom Imageview it's blank...

This is how i do, first my custom ImageView :

```
public class CustomImageView extends AppCompatImageView {

    private Point mTouch;
    private Bitmap mMarker;

    public CustomImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mTouch = new Point();
        mMarker = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.ic_mark);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            mTouch =  new Point(Math.round(event.getX()), Math.round(event.getY()));

        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        super.onDraw(c);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        c.drawBitmap(mMarker, mTouch.x, mTouch.y, paint);
     }

}
```

And Where i use it :

```
....
mCustomImageView = (CustomImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.mypic);
....
File imgFile = new File(getContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),"mypic.jpg");
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
Bitmap myMutableBitmap = myBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565,true);
mCanvas = new Canvas(myMutableBitmap);
mCustomImageView.draw(mCanvas);
```

Then nothing shows... seems that mCustomImageView is empty, and of course onDraw is never fired as i can't draw on it.

But if i use this :

```
mCustomImageView.setImageBitmap(myMutableBitmap);
```

Then the image is showing, and touch events are sent. But i think this way i don't draw on the canvas, and onDraw is not fired as well...

Any hint ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onDraw` is not called after touch event.Adding `invalidate()` to `onTouchEvent` to force refresh may resolve your problem.